# Поиск и замена js

Tags: javascript, jquery, поиск, замена

Есть некий html в переменной. Нужно найти все ссылки и заменить href каждой по принципу: href первой ссылки - текст первого элемента массива, href второй ссылки - текст второго элемента массива и т. д. Ссылок в тексте может быть от 0 до бесконечности. Измененный текст нужно поместить в переменную.
 
Пытался так 
`$(text).find('a').get(i).attr('href', $href[i])` - обижается на attr. 
Так 
`$(text).find('a:eq('+i+')').attr('href', $href[i])` - тоже не то.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: > _Измененный текст нужно поместить в переменную._ имеется ввиду только измененные ссылки? Или вся переменная `text`, в которой поменялись ссылки?

Comment: Вся переменная text, в которой поменялись ссылки

Comment: Пробовал так:

....

// result - html c измененными ссылками
const result = $(text)

// Если в этом месте сделать console.log(result.html()) - в консоль выводится одна ссылка (html)

result.find('a[href]').each((i, el) => {
   el.href = links[i];
});

console.log(result.html());

Comment: Что? Куда? Где вы это делаете? С каким текстом? В моем ответе, как и в ответе vp_arth есть интерактивный пример, то есть явно, вы делаете что-то не то, или хотите чего-то другого. Но понять сложно, без реального кода

Comment: Может дело в том, что я беру текст из визуального редактора?

const text = CKEDITOR.instances['content1'].getData();

если сразу после этого сделать

            const result = $(text);
            console.log(result.html())

в консоле одна ссылка. Если просто  console.log(text) - весь текст

Comment: что за `CKEDITOR`? `result.html()` сразу после `const result = $(text)` должен выводить тот же текст, что и `console.log(text)`, потому что ничего не меняется

Comment: CKEDITOR - экземпляр класса (не уверен в этом термине) визуального редактора. Нужный мне текст находится в этом редакторе. Так CKEDITOR.instances['content1'].getData() я получаю доступ к тексту в редакторе. Нужно произвести изменения в ссылках и поместить текст обратно в редактор. И все же result.html() сразу после const result = $(text) отличается. text = CKEDITOR.instances['content1'].getData() я получаю текст и могу обойти ссылки в нем. Все остальное не получается

Comment: стоит добавить в вопрос инфу про `CKEDITOR`, потому не понятно с чем приходится работать

Comment: И чем отличается? Что изменяется?

Comment: Текст из CKEDITOR такой же как текст, полученный из textarea var text = $('#textarea').val()

Comment: а в чем различие между `result.html()`?

Comment: Текст буквально console.log(text) (часть 1):

<h3><a href="https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru" target="_blank">Google Переводчик</a></h3>

<p><a href="https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru" target="_blank"><cite>https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru</cite></a></p>

<ol>
 <li role="menuitem">&nbsp;</li>
 <li role="menuitem">&nbsp;</li>
</ol>

Comment: Часть 2

<p>Бесплатный сервис&nbsp;<em>Google</em>&nbsp;позволяет мгновенно переводить слова, фразы и веб-страницы с английского на более чем 100 языков и обратно.</p>

<h3><a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.translate&amp;hl=ru" target="_blank">Приложения в Google Play &ndash; Google Переводчик</a></h3>

Comment: console.log(result.html()):

<a href="https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru" target="_blank">Google Переводчик</a>

Comment: Текст первый попавшийся

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const text = `
  <div>
   <a href="link.one.ru">Link</a>
   <ul>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li><a href="link.two.ru">3</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div>
     <a href="link.three.ru">
       <img src="some.pic.ru">
     </a>
   </div>
  </div>
`;

const links = [
  'google.com',
  'yandex.ru',
  'vk.com'
];


// result - html c измененными ссылками
const result = $(text)
result.find('a[href]').each((i, el) => {
   el.href = links[i];
});

console.log(result.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Так как у вас результат выборки - множество ссылок, нужно итерировать их все.

```
$(text).find('a').each(function(index) {
  $(this).attr('href', $href[index]);
});
```

Пример:

```js
    const text = `<div>
    Текст с <a href=1>некоторым</a> <a href=1>количеством</a> <a href=1>ссылок</a>
    </div>`;
    const el = $(text);
    const $href = [
      '/link1',
      '/link2',
      '/link3',
    ];

    const res = el.find('a').each(function(index) {
      $(this).attr('href', $href[index]);
    });
    
    console.log(el.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Для обратной итерации(Хуже, потому что больше походов в DOM):

```js
const text = `<div>
    Текст с <a href=1>некоторым</a> <a href=1>количеством</a> <a href=1>ссылок</a>
    </div>`;
    const el = $(text);
    const $href = [
      '/link1',
      '/link2',
      '/link3',
    ];

    const res = $href.forEach((link, i) => el.find(`a:eq(${i})`).attr('href', link));
    
    console.log(el.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

*Второй код в вопросе почти правильный - он делает то, что нужно, но во временном объекте `$(text)`. Результат получить проблематично) Обратите внимание, что у меня манипуляции производятся над объектом `el`, из которого в итоге и получается результат*

Comment: У меня обход идет по массиву для замены $href. Количество элементов всегда равно количеству ссылок. $($href).each(function(i){ ... })

Comment: во-во :-) только хотел писать что each не нужен :-)

Comment: @qq2009 > _Количество элементов всегда равно количеству ссылок_, тогда какая разница, что мы иттерируем, ссылки или массив адресов. Если они равны, то можно сразу получить все ссылки и проходя по ним брать значение из адресов

Comment: Делал так:
const text = `<div>
    Текст с <a href=1>некоторым</a> <a href=1>количеством</a> <a href=1>ссылок</a>
    </div>`;
    const el = $(text);

//Формируется массив $href

    const res = el.find('a').each(function(index) {
      $(this).attr('href', $href[index]);
    });
    
    console.log(el.html()); - в результате только последняя ссылка